# How to remove double quotes from react array return?

Tags: javascript

I have a data set like this:

```
["[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555713]", "[25.51177,55.557574]", "[25.509928,55.557512]", "[25.509934,55.557521]"]
```

I want to change into the following:

```
[[25.517202,55.555715], [25.517202,55.555715], [25.517202,55.555715], [25.517202,55.555715], [25.517202,55.555713], [25.51177,55.557574], [25.509928,55.557512], [25.509934,55.557521]]
```

**How to remove the " from the array return using react?**

Answer (score 2):

You can map the array with `JSON.parse`:

```js
const array = ["[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555713]", "[25.51177,55.557574]", "[25.509928,55.557512]", "[25.509934,55.557521]"];

const parsed = array.map(JSON.parse);
console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Hi, I have the result like

0: {id: 1,Name: "A"}
1: {id: 2,Name: "B"}
2: {id: 3,Name: "C"}
3: {id: 4,Name: "D"}
4: {id: 5,Name: "E"}
5: {id: 6,Name: "F"}
6: {id: 7,Name: "G"}

I need below  method

[0,1]
[2,3]
[4,5]

How we maks that @MorKadosh

Answer (score 0):

```
const a=["[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555715]", "[25.517202,55.555713]", "[25.51177,55.557574]", "[25.509928,55.557512]", "[25.509934,55.557521]"]

[...a].map(item=>JSON.parse(item))
```